# How do I clear images from my UIImageView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimage

I have the following code for a compositionalLayout in Swift, but my images are not going away with the reuse of cells.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let myInset: CGFloat = 4.0

    let dataColors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.purple, UIColor.orange, UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.purple, UIColor.systemYellow, UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.purple, UIColor.orange, UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.purple, UIColor.systemYellow]

    let theImages = [
            "MEN_8882","002","003","004","005","006","001","002","003","004","005","006",
            "MEN_8882","002","003","004","005","006","001","002","003","004","005","006"
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(createCustomLayout(), animated: false)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.register(QuickCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
       //configureCollectionView()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1//dataColors.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataColors.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as? QuickCell {
            cell.backgroundColor = dataColors[indexPath.row]
            let mySubView = UIImageView()
            mySubView.image = UIImage(named: theImages[indexPath.row])
            cell.addSubview(mySubView)
            mySubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
            mySubView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: myInset).isActive = true
            mySubView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: myInset).isActive = true
            mySubView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: myInset * (-1)).isActive = true
            mySubView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: myInset * (-1)).isActive = true
            mySubView.clipsToBounds = true
           // mySubView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            mySubView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            //cell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            return cell
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

    }

    func createCustomLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

            let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (section: Int, environment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

                let myItemInset: CGFloat = 2.0

                let leadingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
                leadingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: myItemInset, leading: myItemInset, bottom: myItemInset, trailing: myItemInset)

                let leadingGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.7), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
                let leadingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: leadingGroupSize, subitem: leadingItem, count: 1)

                let trailingGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.3), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
                let trailingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: trailingGroupSize, subitem: leadingItem, count: 5)

                let fullGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
                let fullGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: fullGroupSize, subitems: [leadingGroup, trailingGroup])

                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: fullGroup)

                section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
                section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 0)

                return section
            }
            return layout
        }

}
```

The image "MEN..." is portrait while the rest are landscape, and as i scroll back and forth, i see overlapping images in the items.

the code for QuickCell is empty - I'm not sure what to put ther, some kind of initalization? But it should work anyways, right?

```
import UIKit

class QuickCell: UICollectionViewCell {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A subview of type **UIImageView** is added to your custom Cell (QuickCell) each time your collection view cell is resued. It happens in **cellForRowAt** delegate method.

So, you have to remove previously added image views from your cell first before adding a new one.

I suggest you move your cell configuration code to **QuickCell**.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
    if let quickCell = quickCell as? QuickCell {
        quickCell.backgroundColor = self.dataColors[indexPath.row]
        quickCell.setImage(self.theImages[indexPath.row], insetBy: self.myInset)
        return quickCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Do your custom cell configurations here!

```
class QuickCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    func setImage(_ image: UIImage, insetBy inset: CGFloat) {
        // Remove previously added image views first if any
        for subview in self.subviews where subview.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: inset),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: inset),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: inset * (-1)),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: inset * (-1))
        ])
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed a bit and it works. But I don't undersstand why I cannot link and UIImageView from the StoryBoard and simply change the image? Why do I get a "unwrapped nil" error when the UIImageView is right there? It should be weak or not or what?

Comment: You can achieve this through Storyboard as well. I've encountered an "unwrapped nil" error when I failed to link an IBOutlet to the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `image` from `UIImageView` do the following.

```
yourImageView.image = nil
```

Comment: I've tried now a few versions of that, but it still has overlapping images. I inserted the line: `mySubView.image = nil` just above the line `mySubView.image = UIImage(named: theImages[indexPath.row])` ... should it go somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding subviews inside `cellForItemAt` and this causes the overlapping as cells are dequeued , you need to create an outlet for the imageview **or** create it programmatically  inside the cell like

```
class QuickCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    let mySubView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let myInset: CGFloat = 4.0
        self.contentView.addSubview(mySubView)
        mySubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
        mySubView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: myInset).isActive = true
        mySubView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: myInset).isActive = true
        mySubView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: myInset * (-1)).isActive = true
        mySubView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: myInset * (-1)).isActive = true
        mySubView.clipsToBounds = true
       // mySubView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        mySubView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

With

```
cell.mySubView.image = UIImage(named: theImages[indexPath.row])
```

**or**

```
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as? QuickCell {
        cell.subviews.forEach { 
             if $0.tag == 333 {
               $0.removeFromSuperview()
             }
         }
        cell.backgroundColor = dataColors[indexPath.row]
        let mySubView = UIImageView()
        mySubView.tag = 333
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are adding a new `UIImageView` every time the cell is reused. The ones added in previous interations of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method do not go away, so others are added on top.

These are the problem lines:

```
let mySubView = UIImageView()
mySubView.image = UIImage(named: theImages[indexPath.row])
cell.addSubview(mySubView)
```

It would be better to add the image view once when a cell is initialised (or in storyboard with an outlet) then just set the image in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Uncheck & try]

This is checked by default for UICollectionView, try to uncheck it. It should work for you.